# Order by three columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the database, that has 3 columns. `Name, Stock, Backorders`
What query should I use to get rows like this:

All rows should be sorted alphabetically, but first rows should have products that have `stock > 1`, second should be products that have `stock = 0` but have `backorders = 1` and finally the ones that have stock and `backorders = 0`

Comment: Add some sample data sorted as described. (As formatted text, not images.) Show us your query attempt.

Comment: What should happen when stock=1 or negative or when backorder not equal to 0 or 1?

Comment: i advice you to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide example data and expected results as text formatted data

Comment: Besides "I have the database, that has 3 columns. Name, Stock, Backorders" a database can't contain columns a database contains tables which can contain columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating your english to SQL, your query ordering should include:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE 
    WHEN stock > 1 THEN 0
    WHEN stock = 0 AND backorders > 1 THEN 1
    ELSE 2
  END
```

If you want it sorted into sub-sets like alphabetically, put another clause in after the END (use a comma to separate them) for example:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE 
    WHEN stock > 1 THEN 0
    WHEN stock = 0 AND backorders > 1 THEN 1
    ELSE 2
  END,
  productname
```

Things will be sorted first by the numerical rules you gave, then by productname (change that to whatever column has your name that you wish to sort alphabetically)

Can stock or backorders be less than 0? Figure out where they should fit in the sort order.. At the moment the ELSE catches everything else. This can be changed

Comment: This doesn't sort anything alphabetically.  I didn't post, because I don't understand the query yet.

Comment: I ended up using: ORDER BY CASE WHEN stock > 0 THEN 0 WHEN stock = 0 AND backorders > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2  END, products.name ASC